# Does this have a name? $L^p$-style generalization of a sum.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, terminology

To generalize the Euclidean norm
$$
||x||_2 = \left(\sum_i {x_i}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
we can replace the $2$'s by a real number $p \geq 1$
$$
||x||_p = \left(\sum_i {|x_i|}^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} .
$$

This gives us a basic sum for $p=1$ and for $p \to \infty$ the sum turns into a max operator.

This principle is applied to get other generalizations, such as the [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), the [Rényi entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) and the [Rényi dimension](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Dimension.html). Is there a name for this trick?

As a side question (perhaps for the commenters) have I missed anything? Any other places where replacing a sum by this kind of "power sum" yields a meaningful generalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as $l^p$ spaces.

If your index set $I$ is other than $\mathbb N$, you may write $l^p(I)$.  Of course they are special cases of the spaces $L^p(X,\mu)$, where the measure $\mu$ is a "counting measure".

There are lots of "sequence spaces" that have been studied: see for example, [Lindenstrauss & Tzafriri](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387080724) volume I.